# Remove duplicate in a large list while keeping the named number in R

Tags: r, list, duplicates, unique

I have a very large list (1 582 238 elements) and I would like to delete all the duplicate while keeping the name of the numbers.

my list looks like this

```
$`GUE/NGL.mepid`
[1] 197701
...
$`Verts/ALE.mepid`
[1] 197837
```

It is available here : https://github.com/JMcrocs/MEPVote/blob/master/MEPList.rds

When I use unique(mylist), I lose the name of the numbers.

```
 [[1]]
[1] 197701

[[2]]
[1] 197533

[[3]]
[1] 197521
```

Sadly the list is too big to turn into a data.frame so I have not found a solution.

Please can you help me?

Best Regards,

Comment: ``mylist <- list(`GUE/NGL.mepid` = 197701, `GUE/NGL.mepid` = 197701, `Verts/ALE.mepid` = 197837, xyz = 197837); mylist[!(duplicated(mylist) & duplicated(names(mylist)))]``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df <- readRDS('MEPList.rds')
df1 <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,df))
df2 <- df1[!duplicated(df1$V1),,drop=F]
```

Output:

```
head(df2)

                    V1
GUE.NGL.mepid   197701
GUE.NGL.mepid.1 197533
GUE.NGL.mepid.2 197521
GUE.NGL.mepid.3 187917
GUE.NGL.mepid.4 124986
GUE.NGL.mepid.5 197529
```

Then you could format the `rownames()` to get the names.

Comment: You answered so fast, I can't even accept it yet! Thank you so much! Can you just tell me how to use rownames() to delete the number ? I want to delete ".mepid.1" and so on.

Comment: @JMCrocs I hope that answer can help you! You are using plenty of lists :)

Comment: I am not over yet. I will wait 90 minutes for my last question. R is quite hard to use when you never had a course about it haha but you know...this master's thesis won't finish by itself ;)

Comment: @JMCrocs What did you study for your Master? Most of masters have at least one `R` course now!

Comment: Political Science in a french uni I would have never heard of R if my "hard science" friends talked to me about it haha

Comment: @JMCrocs Oh I understand now, but for sure you will master it :)

Answer (score 2):

Use subsetting with `!duplicated()` instead of `unique()` to keep the names.

```
l <- list(197701, 197837, 197701)
names(l) <- c("GUE/NGL.mepid", "Verts/ALE.mepid", "GUE/NGL.mepid")


# > unique(l)
# [[1]]
# [1] 197701
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 197837
# 
# > l[!duplicated(l)]
# $`GUE/NGL.mepid`
# [1] 197701
# 
# $`Verts/ALE.mepid`
# [1] 197837
```

Or use again `unique()` to retrieve the names of the unique elements.
(`unique()` keeps order of occurrence).

```
res <- unique(l)
names(res) <- unique(names(l))
```

Comment: Good idea! Your example is a named vector, not a list. How about converting it to a list to meet the OP's problem?